# Using JavaScript variable as tablename in select query in PHP form

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using a function in which I'm assigning a variable a `tablename` value like:

```
function mshirt(){
    var tbname='m_shirts';
}
```

**Then in PHP form action section:**

```
include 'database_connection.php';
$tablename=tbname;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $Size=$_POST['size'];
    $Color=$_POST['color'];
    $Code=$_POST['code'];
    $Brand=$_POST['brand'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO `$tablename` (size,color,code,brand) VALUES('$Size','$Color','$Code','$Brand')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        echo("Added Succesfully");
    }
    else 
        echo("Failed to Add");
```

The problem is that it assumes `tbname` to be undefined constant.

Comment: I suppose you are doing an asynchronous request, could you post the code of your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

The error is because of the line:

```
$tablename=tbname;
```

`tbname` is a JS (client-side) variable: you cannot simply enter it into PHP (server-side) and expect it to work. You need to instead send it over as `POST` data to PHP, just like you would other data.

---

**SOLUTION**

If you were doing this by AJAX and jQuery, for example:

```
var tbname = 'm_shirts';

$.ajax({
    url: "path_to_php_file.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {
        tbname: tbname,
        // the rest of form data (the request) to be sent
    }
});
```

And in PHP, you would get this as a regular `$_POST` variable index:

```
$tbname = $_POST["tbname"];
```

(If you were sending the data using a regular form or some other method, you would need to modify this... this is just an example for demonstration.)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to mix languages...

You should send the name of the table via ajax or form and then catch your value with $_GET or $POST